# How to forward fill tumbling window in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have some time series data with a "timestamp" column. The tumbling window function helps generate snapshots like so:

```
val q = cleanDF.withColumn("window", window($"timestamp","5 minutes"))
val w = Window.partitionBy($"window").orderBy($"timestamp".desc)
val snaps = q.withColumn("rn",row_number.over(w)).where($"rn"===1).drop("rn").drop("window")
```

For windows with no data, how do I forward fill with the last known good value?

Comment: sample input and expected output should help you get answers quickly. :)

Comment: @RameshMaharjan Think of a 5-minute interval with no records available.